# Is there a log4net version for Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, logging, log4net, enterprise-library

Is there a log4net version built against Silverlight somewhere?

Failing that, can someone suggest an alternative logging framework to use in Silverlight?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need Clogs (not for your feet, http://clog.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It is LGPL (not GPL). Don't know if it was changed at any point. It's fine to use from your application without releasing your source code

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Logging Application Block](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Enterprise-Library-for-Silverlight-Logging-demo) of the [Enterprise Library Silverlight Integration Pack](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight) from [Microsoft patterns & practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/practices).